# PLS-00221: 'JOBSTAB' is not a procedure or is undefined

Tags: plsql

I'm currently studying PL/SQL and was doing experiment by declaring a private PL/SQL in the package index-by table called `jobs_tab_type` that should be indexed by a string type based on the `jobs.job_id%type`.

Now I really don't want to put it in a package right away and just test it first so first I created it in an anonymous block.

```
DECLARE
    TYPE jobs_tab_type IS TABLE OF jobs%rowtype INDEX BY jobs.job_id%type;
    jobstab jobs_tab_type;
BEGIN

    for rec in(select job_id from jobs)
    LOOP
        jobstab(rec.job_id);
    END LOOP;
END;
```

I compiled it and ran into this error `'PLS-00221: 'JOBSTAB' is not a procedure or is undefined`   .
I don't know what i did wrong based on the documentations i'm currently reading online. But I don't get what is wrong, i didn't even declared a constraint and just referenced it with the data type that is on the database.

Update:
This is the description of my jobs table:

[image]

Comment: jobsstab is the one that i used to reference on the table. It's on the Declare block.

Comment: Hi @BarbarosÖzhan i've updated my code and used jobs.job_id%type to mirror the data type that is on my jobs table, but still i have encountered the problem

Comment: Seems that the data type of the `job_id` is not of type string such as `VARCHAR2`. The data type of index can be either a string type or `PLS_INTEGER`. You can check [this](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/composites.htm#LNPLS99969) out.

Comment: is String and VARCHAR2 different?

Comment: principally No, since `VARCHAR2` is a string type. But `STRING` cannot be data type of a column within a table unlike `VARCHAR2`, but might be used within a PL/SQL code block.

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan but i've used the data type of job_id which is VARCHAR2(10) using the jobs.job_id%type as an index to my table, so it should not have a problem just like the link you have shown

Comment: You can check this [test case](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=797bdac35dd1b28b7d3de2eb419400a7)

Comment: I checked it, thanks. But my job_id is originally is varchar2 as seen on the description on the table. Is it because of the min_salary and max_salary that is causing the problem since they are numbers?

Answer (score 0):

I changed the following code to:

DECLARE
TYPE jobs_tab_type IS TABLE OF jobs%rowtype INDEX BY jobs.job_id%type;
jobstab jobs_tab_type;
BEGIN

```
for rec in(select job_id from jobs)
LOOP
    jobstab(rec.job_id) := rec;
END LOOP;
```

END;

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).